# PHP Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I read everything I could about this error without being able to find any solution.

I have a simple page that looks like this:

```
$xmlfile = "/var/www/marees.xml"; //Fichier dans lequel récupérer les données
$ent = new DOMDocument();
$ent->load($xmlfile);

if(!(@$ent->load($xmlfile)))
{
    echo "Unable to load : " . $xmlfile;
    exit();
}
```

I get three times out of four, randomly this error:

> PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/var/www/marees.xml" in /var/www/marees/test2.php on line 7

When I restart Apache, the script works fine for 5 minutes, then the error starts to appear.

XML file weighs 595 kB, is present and readable.

What might be the problem?

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_exists($xmlfile));` return?

Comment: try : chmod 777 /var/www/marees.xml

Comment: I've tried chmod 777, same result (the file was already readable/writable by www-data)

the `var_dump(file_exists($xmlfile));` return always : bool(true) (even if there is an error in the load xmlfile or not)

Comment: Do you have Another Idea ? :-)

Comment: Most often if you enable error logging and raise error reporting to the highest level, you find more information about that error in your error log. Take that information and contact your server administrator to discuss the issue.

Answer (score 10):

add this command to the top of your script:

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
```

For more details see [this link](http://pyd.io/f/topic/failed-to-load-external-entity-boot-confmanifest-xml/).

Comment: Is there an alternative solution for PHP 8+ as this method has been deprecated? See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php

Answer (score 1):

```
public mixed DOMDocument::load ( string $filename [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

The [function declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) carries with it an optional parameter named `$options` where:

> **options**
>   Bitwise OR of the [libxml option constants](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php).

The usage of the `LIBXML_NOWARNING` constant solves the issue for me:

```
$ent->load($xmlfile, LIBXML_NOWARNING);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was **copying some files in the root directory of XML**. And this **process was changing permission of the root directory recursively**. So I just **changed the permission using below code after copying files and it worked**.

```
        mkdir($rootDirectoryAddress, 0777, true);
```