# Checking number of results of a Google search in a PHP script

Tags: php, search, google-api, google-search, phrase

Is it possible to check number of Google search results of a certain phrase in a PHP script with Google API? I am curious if it can be done someway. If yes, what should I do?

EDIT

Okay, according to drakin8564 advices it is my function:

```
function google(String $text) {

        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q="'.$text.'"'); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        $xml = new DOMDocument();

        $xml->loadHTMLFile($output);

        $string = $xml->getElementById('resultStats');

        $string = str_replace('Około ', '', $string); 
        $string = str_replace(',', '', $string);
        $results = intval($string);

        if($results>0) {

            curl_close($ch);            
            return true; 
        } else {
        curl_close($ch);     
        return false;
        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        } 
        }
```

NOTE: "Około" means "About" in Polish, Also I have a warning:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage" lang="pl"><head><meta content="text/ in C:\xampp2\htdocs\file.php on line 19
```

And here is an implementation

```
if(google("flower") == true){
            echo "search results exist";

        } else {
            echo "results don't exist";
        }

if(google("7dsa8dsaza") == true){
            echo "search results exist";

        } else {
            echo "results don't exist";
        }
```

Unfortunately there is a problem because both examples cause "search results exist" output while the results for "7dsa8dsaza" do not exist. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it with Google API, but you could curl to https://www.google.com/search?q={your+search+words}

You should be able to throw that html into an object using DomDocument. An estimated number of results is in a div with id="resultStats"

Examples of using the php curl functions:
[PHP cURL Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)

Docs for DomDocument, has some examples in the comments section:
[PHP DomDocument Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

EDIT: Example to get only the number from the resultStats element:

```
$string = "About 214,000,000 results (0.41 seconds)"; 
$string = str_replace('About ', '', $string); 
$string = str_replace(',', '', $string);
$results = intval($string);
```

Comment: can you show me some code because I do not know what are you exactly talking about

Comment: I added some links to documentation. DomDocument is a built in php class that you can use to parse html or xml into an object. Curl is used to send a request to a specified url and retrieve the response.

Comment: In this case your curl response from google would be the html of the google search page.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a beginner. I have never heard before about cURL and DomDocument. Can you provide some code with implemented solutions for my problem?

Comment: The first curl example from the page I linked above should work with the url that you are requesting instead of "example.com". After setting $output to the return of curl_exec(), create an instance of DomDocument() like this: $xml = new DOMDocument(); Then pass the $output variable into the DomDocument function loadHTMLFile() like this:$xml->loadHTMLFile($output); You can then call $xml->getElementById('resultStats'); and that will give you the contents of the div that has an approximation of the number of search results.

Comment: You used a . instead of -> in your condition. Currently this is trying to concatenate a function to your $xml object rather than call a function on the object.

Comment: Okay, I have changed my question again. Please, come and see:)

Comment: You need to parse the number out of that element. Something like this would work for that:
$string = "About 214,000,000 results (0.41 seconds)";
$string = str_replace('About ', '', $string);
$string = str_replace(',', '', $string);

However, your if is backwards. if that result is > 0 you should be returning true instead of false. If pulling the number out of that result does not work it is then likely that the curl failed. If so you can check with curl_error(). That function will give you the last error message from the curl function if there is one.

Comment: Can you post it as a code in your edited answer? Because here it's quite hard to understand.

Comment: I put that example as code in an edit on the answer

Comment: It still does not work. I have edited my code again.

Comment: The answers on this question should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489845/php-warning-domdocumentload-i-o-warning-failed-to-load-external-entity

Comment: I edited my code again by adding:  libxml_disable_entity_loader(false); and it is still not working. Can you send me working code, because I am just a beginner and I can do something wrong:)?