# loadHTMLFile working on localhost, but not working on server

Tags: php, html, dom

any ideas why this code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    
$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://gpwcatalyst.pl/ajaxindex.php?action=BSInstrument&start=listFull&lang=PL&format=html&download_xls=1&bsi_instrument=OKR,OKM,LZH,LZP,OSP,OPD&bsi_rodzaj=N&currencies=PLN&table_order=');
    
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

works fine on localhost but not working on server and gives this warnings:

> Warning: PHP Startup: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /test.php on line 14
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://gpwcatalyst.pl/ajaxindex.php?action=BSInstrument&start=listFull&lang=PL&format=html&download_xls=1&bsi_instrument=OKR,OKM,LZH,LZP,OSP,OPD&bsi_rodzaj=N&currencies=PLN&table_order=" in /test.php on line 14

Line 14 is `$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://...`

Where should I look for a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it worked locally? It could be your warnings in XAMPP were not showing this.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Locally the output is a simple html table from which I can retrieve data and send it to db. The same script runs on real server gives above warnings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489845/php-warning-domdocumentload-i-o-warning-failed-to-load-external-entity)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to find another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think your server can't resolve that host.
so if you have ssh you can use ping or curl -L commands to check it.
or if you have not ssh you can create a PHP CURL script to check it.